# Distribution function of $ X(\omega):=\frac{1}{\lambda} \ln \frac{1}{1-\omega},$ in Lebesgue measure

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables, exponential-distribution

I am having trouble in finding the right approach to this exercise:

> Define the probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{A},P) =((0,1), \mathcal{B}, \mu)$ with $\mu$ as the Lebesgue measure and $ \mathcal{B}$ the Borel-$\sigma$-algebra. 
>   Find the distribution function of the random variable $$ X(\omega):=\frac{1}{\lambda} \ln \frac{1}{1-\omega},$$
>   where $\lambda$ is a positive parameter.

I know that the definition of a distribution function is $P(X\leq x) $, but to be honest I'm a bit overwhelmed and don't know how to start. Does it have to do with Lebesgue integration? Because that's what we were doing last week in the lecture. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where did you get this please? This seems to be precisely what I'm looking for here [Dumb question: Computing expectation without change of variable formula](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2690542)

Comment: It's one of my exercises for my probability theory I lecture. So it's pretty random that it's helping you. But still nice to hear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's take this one step at a time.

You have to figure out $P(X\leq x)$, the probability of the set $\{\omega\mid X(\omega)\leq x\}$, right? Well, let's try and get a feel for what set that is, first of all. It's going to be a subset of $(0, 1)$, so we're just talking about a set of real numbers here, maybe an interval or something.

So, for which $\omega$ do we have $\frac{1}{\lambda} ln \frac{1}{1-\omega}\leq x$, where $x$ is a constant in $(0, 1)$? This is just solving an inequality. At the end of it, you end up with some set $\{\omega\mid X(\omega)\leq x\}$.

Now, what is the probability of that set? Well, the probability measure in play here is just the Lebesgue measure $\mu$. You're being asked to compute $\mu(\{\omega\mid X(\omega)\leq x\})$, in other words, just the length of that set.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So i gotta use the Lebesgue measure. But how can i consider the whole interval (0,1) for x? I can see the inequality, but for the distribution function don't I have to view every case in this uncountable infinite interval?

Comment: @d237 Yes, determining the distribution function means computing $P(X<x)$ for every $x\in \mathbb R$. But that's not a problem. Just let $x$ be a constant like you would in any algebra problem. If I solve $ax+b=0$, I have to prove my answer works "for all $a,b$", but that doesn't mean I have to do an uncountably infinite amount of work.

Answer (score 2):

Definition $$P(X \le x) := P(\omega | X(\omega) \le x)$$

Two steps in computing $P(X \le x)$:

1. Find all $\omega$ s.t. $X(\omega) \le x$
2. Compute the probability of all those $\omega$'s.

For $x \le 0$, $P(X\leq x) = P(\emptyset) = 0$

Let $\omega \in \Omega = (0,1)$. For $x > 0$, $X(\omega) \le x$

Step 1:

$$ \iff \frac1{\lambda}\ln(\frac{1}{1-\omega}) \le x$$

$$ \iff \omega \le \frac{e^{\lambda x} - 1}{e^{\lambda x}}$$

$$ \iff \omega \in (0,1) \cap (-\infty,\frac{e^{\lambda x} - 1}{e^{\lambda x}})$$

$$ \iff \omega \in (0,\frac{e^{\lambda x} - 1}{e^{\lambda x}})$$

Step 2:

$$\mu(\omega | \omega \in (0,\frac{e^{\lambda x} - 1}{e^{\lambda x}}))$$

$$= \mu((0,\frac{e^{\lambda x} - 1}{e^{\lambda x}}))$$

$$= \frac{e^{\lambda x} - 1}{e^{\lambda x}}$$

Therefore, $F_X(x) = P(X \le x) = (1-e^{-\lambda x})1_{x \ge 0} \to f_X(x) = \lambda e^{-\lambda x}1_{x \ge 0}$, which we recognise as the exponential distribution.